# Present tense vs. future tense following a conditional

Tags: tenses, conditionals, future, present-tense

> 1. If you ask without any background, many people *are* likely to assume you are just too lazy to do the work yourself.
> 2. If you ask without any background, many people *will* likely assume you are just too lazy to do the work yourself.

Shouldn't (2) be better than (1)?

I searched for "future tense vs. present tense", but didn't find anything helpful in reference to the posed problem.

Furthermore, I found on [grammar.ccc](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional2.htm) that an '*if* + present tense' clause should be followed by a main clause of the form '*will* + infinitive/present tense/imperative'; so, at least according to that reliable source, (1) would be wrong.

Comment: "Shouldn't 2 be better than 1?" Not really. Maybe because of the word "many," but not because of the verb tense. "People are likely to ..." and "many [people] will likely ..." are both perfectly acceptable. If anything, "people are likely to" (without the "many") sounds more natural.

Comment: @Elberich, The website you link to in your edit gives examples in the 'first', 'second' and 'third' conditionals only. But as Swan in _Practical English Usage_ (p246) states: _Although these are useful structures to practise, it is important to realise that there are many different structures with if, and that they do not really divide into three main kinds_. An example Swan lists of the present tense in both clauses is: _If you want to learn an instrument, you have to practise._

Comment: Both #1 and #2 versions are fine. (As to the "likely" issue: *"If no one clapped last night, it is likely they didn't appreciate his performance."* -- it talks about the past, not the future.)

Answer (score 1):

*If-clauses* that predict the future are commonly followed by a main clause with *will + infinitive*:

> If you ask without any background, many people will assume you are
>   just too lazy ... .

What complicates the present example is the use of the word *likely*. This word already has a future implication so there is no need to use *will* too. For example:

> He is likely to be late = It is probable that he will be late.

For this reason the first of the OP's sentence is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Shoe, according to you, what's the reason why the answer doesn't have an upvote yet?

Comment: @Elberich, Maybe readers of my answer did not feel that the discussion of _likely_ in this context was helpful. Nevertheless, you might wish to know that the expression _are likely to_ (your sentence 1) is much more common than _will likely_ (sentence 2), as an nGram comparison shows. This could be considered supportive evidence for my contention that sentence 2 cannot be considered 'better'. Moving on from the discussion of likely, Sentence 1 uses the zero conditional (same tense in both clauses), which is a perfectly valid way of referring to inevitable consequences.

Comment: nGram: is likely to, will likely (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+likely+to%2C+will+likely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20likely%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20likely%3B%2Cc0)